# Accessing age of pixels on reddit/r/place

Tags: python, json, reddit

I wrote the following script to access the age of pixels in the reddit's r/place experiment:

```
import requests as req
import json
from time import sleep
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
import sys

username = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]
location = sys.argv[3]


s = req.Session()
s.mount('https://www.reddit.com', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=5))
s.headers["User-Agent"] = "WebDev Alliance" 
r = s.post("https://www.reddit.com/api/login/{}".format(username),
       data={"user": username, "passwd": password, "api_type": "json"})
s.headers['x-modhash'] = r.json()["json"]["data"]["modhash"]

def main(rows,columns):
    mylist = [[0 for x in range(columns)] for x in range(rows)]
    r = {}
    dic1 = {}
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(columns):
            mylist[i][j] = '%s;%s'%(i,j)
    for j in range(columns):
        for i in range(rows):
            message = "Probing absolute pixel x="+str(i)+"&y="+str(j)
            print(message)
            while True:
                 r = s.get('https://www.reddit.com/api/place/pixel.json?x='+str(i)+'&y='+str(j), timeout=60)
                 if r.status_code == 200:
                     dic1[str(i)+' '+str(j)] = r.json()
                     sleep(0.1)
                     break
                 else:
                     sleep(1)   
                     print("ERROR: ", r, r.text)
     with open(location, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(dic1, outfile, sort_keys = True, indent = 4)

main(1000,1000)
```

However, there are two clear problems with the script:

1. It will take ages to complete at best (0.1 sec * 1000 * 1000 ~= 28 hours)
2. My IP might be banned

plus the code itself does not handle exceptions.

That is why I am wondering if there is a better method of accessing the last modification date of each of the pixels on reddit.com/r/place

Thanks!

Comment: For one, you're doing them all one after the other, when you could be doing many calls simultaneously. If you run multiple queries at once, you could increase the speed by a huge amount. Also, I am not sure of the purpose of sleeping in your code, especially the fact that you sleep for a whole second if there is an error. Regarding a blocked IP, that's out of the scope of Stack Overflow and is between you and the site. Your IP may be blocked if you are hitting the API too fast, though, so making sure you don't exceed their rate limits might be a good thing to do.

Comment: @RandomDavis could you point me in the direction of how I could be doing many calls simultaneously?

Comment: I don't know the best way to do many network calls at once, but in general in Python, you can use its multiprocessing or threading libraries.